# Build and respond to events on multiple check boxes

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am attempting to make a form with multiple check boxes, based on the array passed to the form creation function. I can calculate the correct location based on the count of what checkbox I am at is, but I am having trouble (I think) dealing with events. I have this for now (partial code, obviously)

```
    $checkboxCount = 1
    foreach ($year in $years) {
        $checkbox = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
        $checkbox.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
        $checkbox.Location  = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,($checkbox.Size.Height*$checkboxCount-10))
        $checkbox.Text = "Revit $year"
        $checkbox.Checked = $true
        $Form.Controls.Add($checkbox)
        $checkbox.Add_CheckStateChanged({
            $results.$year = $checkbox.Checked
        })
        $checkboxCount ++
    }
```

and the check boxes are created correctly, but when I return `$results` from the function they are all True. I am basing the code off of this, which works but with a static number of check boxes.

```
function checkbox_test{
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

    $results = @{
        one = $true
        two = $true
    }
    $optionCount = 2

    # Set the size of your form
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form | Format-List *
    $form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
    $form.ShowInTaskbar = $false
    $Form.width = 300
    $Form.height = 150
    $Form.Text = ”Px Tools Updater”

    # Set the font of the text to be used within the form
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12)
    $Form.Font = $Font

    # create your checkbox 
    $checkbox1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $checkbox1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,7)
    $checkbox1.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
    $checkbox1.Text = "One"
    $checkbox1.Checked = $true

    $Form.Controls.Add($checkbox1)

    # create your checkbox 
    $checkbox2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $checkbox2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,27)
    $checkbox2.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
    $checkbox2.Text = "Two"
    $checkbox2.Checked = $true
    $Form.Controls.Add($checkbox2)  

    # Add an OK button
    $OKButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,70)
    $OKButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,30)
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})
    $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

    #Add a cancel button
    $CancelButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(225,100)
    $CancelButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,30)
    $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    $CancelButton.Margin = 0
    $CancelButton.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})
    $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

    $checkbox1.Add_CheckStateChanged({
        $results.one = $checkbox1.Checked
    })
    $checkbox2.Add_CheckStateChanged({
        $results.two = $checkbox2.Checked
    })


    # Activate the form
    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog() 

$results
}
```

I am not sure if I am going wrong with the way I am referencing the results hash table, or maybe the entire approach is wrong?

Edit: I had a thought, that $year is meaningless in the event handler, so I added

```
$checkbox.Name = $year
```

and revised the event handler to

```
$results.($checkbox.Name) = $checkbox.Checked
```

and

```
$results.($Self.Name) = $checkbox.Checked
```

But no joy with either. But what is weird is that using $self results in an odd extra key being added to $return. It has no key name, but the value matches the last change made to any checkbox.

EDIT #2: In further testing, I changed the handler to

```
$results.2019 = $checkbox.Checked
```

expecting that to mean any change results in that change applied to the 2019 key. not so. So I am thinking it relates to the way hash tables are passed and referenced and likely I am doing this all wrong. Perhaps worrisome is the fact that I can find tons of information on making check boxes react to and change other parts of the form, but so far nothing on just getting results back.

EDIT #3: OK, seems the answer (of sorts) is there is no need for event handlers, because I only really care about end state anyway. So, with some extra cleanup to also handle Cancel I have this, and it works. Still curious how, or if, I could interact directly with $results from an event handler though.

```
function checkbox_test{
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

    $years = @('2016', '2017', '2018', '2019')
    $optionCount = $years.Count

    # Set the size of your form
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
    $form.ShowInTaskbar = $false
    $Form.width = 300
    $Form.height = ($years.Count * 30 + 50 + 40) #150
    $Form.Text = ”Px Tools Updater”

    # Set the font of the text to be used within the form
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12)
    $Form.Font = $Font

    # create Checkboxes
    $checkboxCount = 1
    foreach ($year in $years) {
        $checkbox = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
        $checkbox.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
        $checkbox.Location  = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,($checkbox.Size.Height*$checkboxCount-10))
        $checkbox.Text = "Revit $year"
        $checkbox.Name = $year
        $checkbox.Checked = $true
        $Form.Controls.Add($checkbox)
        $checkboxCount ++
    }

    # Add an OK button
    $OKButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,30)
    $OKButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,($form.DisplayRectangle.Height - $OKButton.Size.Height - 10))
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.Add_Click({
        $Form.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
        $Form.Close()
    })
    $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

    #Add a cancel button
    $CancelButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(60,30)
    $CancelButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(($form.DisplayRectangle.Width - $CancelButton.Size.Width - 10),($form.DisplayRectangle.Height - $CancelButton.Size.Height - 10))
    $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    $CancelButton.Add_Click({
        $Form.Close()
    })
    $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)




    # Activate the form
    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    if ($Form.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK') {
        $results = New-Object Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
        foreach ($control in $form.Controls) {
            if ($years -contains $control.Name) {
                $results.Add($control.Name, $control.Checked)
            }
        }
    } else {
        $results = $null
    }
    [void] $Form.Dispose

$results
}

#Call the function
$returned = checkbox_test

Foreach ($key in $returned.keys) {
    Write-Host "[$key] $($returned.$key)!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` loop used to assign each checkbox event handler above effectively overwrites the previous one, and therefore you only capture the last one. (2019)

Instead, assign the event hander [the way it's traditionally done in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/event-handlers-overview-windows-forms):

```
$results = New-Object Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary;
foreach ($year in $years) {
    $checkbox = new-object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
    $Form.Controls.Add($checkbox);
    $checkbox.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
    $checkbox.Location  = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,($checkbox.Size.Height*$checkboxCount-10))
    $checkbox.Text = "Revit $year"
    $checkbox.Name = $year
    $checkbox.Checked = $true
    $results.Add($year, $checkbox.Checked);
    # HERE!
    $checkbox.Add_CheckStateChanged({
        # $this -eq sender, optionally $_ -eq EventArgs
        $year = $this.name;
        $results.$year = $this.Checked;
    });      
    $checkboxCount++
}
```